# NMEAlistener not working in gingerbread

Tags: android

I wrote some code which basically spits out NMEA sentences. The code worked on froyo and did exactly what I wanted.  Now However, when I got the gingerbread upgrade, it is no longer working.  Has anyone else had this issue?

I'm using a Nexus One and will post some code later if you guys need it.

Thanks

Sorry, i was very busy lately.  Here is the code finally:

```
public class GPSTest extends Activity {
    TextView mTextView;
    Button mStartButton, mStopButton;
    LocationManager mLocationManager;
    boolean isRegistered;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);

        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }
    void registerListeners(){
        if(!isRegistered){
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 , 0, mLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.addNmeaListener(mListener);

            isRegistered=true;
        }
    }
    void deregisterListeners(){
        if (isRegistered){
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.removeNmeaListener(mListener);

            isRegistered=false;
        }
    }
    OnClickListener mButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v==mStartButton){
                registerListeners();
            }else{
                deregisterListeners();
            }

        }

    };
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        deregisterListeners();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        registerListeners();
    }
    NmeaListener mListener = new NmeaListener(){

        @Override
        public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mTextView.append("\n"+nmea);
        }

    };
    LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: post the code, i dont think the nmea listener is broken in GB

Comment: please see the code above.  One more person has mentioned that they are having the same problem after upgrade to GingerBread.

Answer (score 2):

Documented bug in the post-Froyo implementations on some handsets (Nexus One I can confirm, Xoom anecdotally seems to be fine). Haven't heard from the folks using the Nexus S, but it sounds like they are fine.

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15500 for more detail.

Edit: trying to poke the folks at Google to see if some clarification can be found.

Edit 2: Oh yeah, verified that 2.2 works (HTC Incredible, Nexus One worked BEFORE the 2.3 update), but the same Nexus One no longer works after updating to 2.3.3.

Comment: Yes,  I started that thread after i did not get a response here.  Google seems to be non responsive on this as well.